# Run local script on remote server with ruby net-ssh

Tags: ruby, bash, ssh, net-ssh

Currently I have this for running scripts on remote servers:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'optparse'
USER = 'user1'
PASS = 'happy123'
HOST = 'server1'


Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh|
    results = ssh.exec!("/user/blah.sh arg1 blah")
    puts results
end
```

This works fine, but requires that the script I need to run is on the local server.  I am trying to find a way to execute a local script against a remote server.  With ssh I can just do this:

```
ssh user1@server1 -s 'bash -s' < blah.sh
```

I just don't know how to redirect my script in to my bash command with ssh.exec.  Help?
Also, I really need to do like below for it:

```
 ssh user1@server1 -s 'bash -s' -- < check_mountpoints.sh -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: You can't run a local script on a remote box, it has to reside on the far machine. Local scripts run on the local CPU, right? If you want it to run remotely, you can scp it over and then run it, or script the commands to remotely create it then execute it via SSH.

Comment: You mean you can't with ruby/net-ssh?  Or with bash, because the bottom line in my description works perfectly.  I just want to use ruby so I don't have to pass my password, or generate keys and distribute them.

Comment: You're basically doing what I said: "script the commands to remotely create it then execute it" in your last sample. The command-line ssh session sends the contents of the file and runs it remotely. Check "[Shell Service](http://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-5.html#s3)"; The [`send_data`](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Channel.html#method-i-send_data) method is your friend. Also read http://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-5.html#s4

Comment: @cashman04 http://askubuntu.com/a/26370/226852